# How to rewrite url in Symfony3

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony-3.3

i'm new in symfony. I'm trying to rewrite Url in symfony3. I change `.htaccess` in `web` folder but it didn't work.
The url is `"/view/item/18"`, it should be `"/view/item?view_detail_id=18"`. I just try `sudo a2enmod rewrite` but it didn't work. 
I found this question for a long time but seem don't have more document or tutorial about it. Hope someone can help me.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Symfony uses rewriting out of the box, just take a look at the web/.htaccess file:

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]